# [Core Data]: data: <fault>

Tags: swift, core-data

The `questions` parameter in the function is full, but I cannot transfer assignments to `questionsCD.questions?.questionList`.

**The `id` and `title` variables are `not nil`. Those variables are working in a healthy way.**

In Console output, `questions` return `nil`.

**I cannot assign the `questionList` variable in the `QuestionsNSSecureCoding` class, so I think it returns nil. Why ?**

You can examine the Core Data Entity image to see the `questionsCD.questions?.questionList` in more detail.

[image]

**Core Data Save Function:**

```
func saveSelectedQuestion(questionTitle: String, id: String, questions: [QuestionList]) {
    
    let questionsCD = QuestionCD(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
    questionsCD.title = questionTitle
    questionsCD.id = id
    questionsCD.questions?.questionList = questions
    print("nil test: \(questionsCD.questions?.questionList ?? [])")
    
    do {
        try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
    } catch let error {
        print("Failed to save selected category: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

**Core Data Get Function:**

```
func getSelectedQuestion(questionID: String) -> [QuestionCD] {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<QuestionCD> = QuestionCD.fetchRequest()
    let search = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", questionID)
    print("search: \(search)")
    fetchRequest.predicate = search
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    print("request predicate: \(String(describing: fetchRequest.predicate))")
    do {
        return try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error {
        print("get hata: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

**Console Output:**

```
selectedQuestionCD [<QuestionCD: 0x2800e8e60> (entity: QuestionCD; id: 0x9d00d28ec7359eb0 <x-coredata://089E80AC-0E4F-4303-BF8F-47C31EC70ED4/QuestionCD/p2>; data: {
    id = "agustos_test_1";
    questions = nil;
    title = "A\U011fustos Test 1";
})]
```

**Core Data Entity:**

[image]

**Questions NSSecure Coding:**

```
public class QuestionsNSSecureCoding: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    
    public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true
    
    var questionList: [QuestionList]

    
    required init(questions: [QuestionList]) {
        self.questionList = questions

    }
    
    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(questionList, forKey: "questionList")

    }
    
    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        
        questionList = coder.decodeObject(of: NSArray.self, forKey: "questionList") as? Array<QuestionList> ?? []

    }
}
```

**Questions Value Transformer:**

```
@objc(QuestionsValueTransformer)
final class QuestionsValueTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {
    static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: String(describing: QuestionsValueTransformer.self))
 
    override static var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        return [QuestionsNSSecureCoding.self]
    }
    
    public static func register() {
            let transformer = QuestionsValueTransformer()
            ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
        }
}
```

**My Custom Model:**

```
class QuestionContainer: Codable {
    
    var questionCategories: [Question]
    
    init(questionCategories: [Question]) {
        self.questionCategories = questionCategories
    }
}

class Question: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    var title: String
    var id: String
    var questions: [QuestionList]
    
        init(title: String, id: String, questions: [QuestionList]) {
            self.title = title
            self.id = id
            self.questions = questions
        }
}

class QuestionList: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: String
    
    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `questionCD.questions` is nil, so the line

```
questionsCD.questions?.questionList = questions
```

does nothing.  You need to create an instance of `QuestionsNSSecureCoding` with the correct questions array, and assign that to the `questions` property:

```
questionsCD.questions = QuestionsNSSecureCoding(questions: questions)
```

Comment: I got another error.```NSForwarding: warning: object 0x281f7adc0 of class 'CoreDataTest.QuestionList' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[CoreDataTest.QuestionList replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
2021-08-22 22:52:46.714021+0300 CoreDataTest[40973:3328391] Unrecognized selector -[CoreDataTest.QuestionList replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]```

Comment: error here.. ```public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(questionList, forKey: "questionList")

    }```

Comment: Sorry - now you're in the realms of NSSecureCoding and Codable, which is outside my experience.